# .htaccess redirect in certain cases only

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to Redirect to www.domain.com/go404 in these cases:

> www.domain.com
>
> www.domain.com/
>
> domain.com
>
> domain.com/

But not, when they type (I have that covered)

```
   www.domain.com/subdomain or
   domain.com/subdomain
```

Presently, my .htaccess code has this snippet:

```
 # This sends "just domain" visits to 404
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ [NC] 
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/go404 [R=301,L]

 # This one makes a NON WWW become a WWW
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ [NC] 
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

 # This strips the trailing slash
 RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(\?.*)?$ $1$2 [R=301,L]
```

Can anyone tell me how to set up the condition so it ONLY allows domains written without the trailing slash and/or subfolder string? As indicated above, those should redirect to 404.

Answer (score 0):

These rules should do what you need:

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ [NC] 
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$ [NC] 
 RewriteRule ^$ go404 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll check them today and get back to you.

Comment: Ahhhh! The great make it seem so easy! 
Thank you SO much for your answer. It's a simple solution that works perfectly in all my test scenarios. I was specially concerned about www.domain.com/admin. With my previous attempt I could open the admin panel but could not save any changes. Now it works great.
Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to hear it works :) If it works, you can accept the answer.